# Polymer calling functions in script

Tags: polymer

I am trying to write the polymer app.

The problem arises in the code below, while calling updateItems in onLogin.

It does no recognize the function.

I tried this.updateItems too

```
  Polymer({

  is: 'my-view1',

  updateItems : function(snapshot) {...},
  onLogin : function(user) {
      this.ref = ... ;
      this.ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
          updateItems(snapshot);
  });
  },
});
```

Any suggestion how to call updateItems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a reference to `this` like:

```
  updateItems : function(snapshot) {...},
  onLogin : function(user) {
      var self = this.
      this.ref = ... ;
      this.ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
          self.updateItems(snapshot);
  });
  },
```